# Let $A_j \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $j \in \Bbb N$. Show that $\mu\left(\bigcap_{j\ge k} A_j\right) \le \inf_{j \ge k} \mu(A_j)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure-space. Let $A_j \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $j \in \Bbb N$. Show that $\mu\left(\bigcap_{j\ge k} A_j\right) \le \inf_{j \ge k} \mu(A_j)$ and that $\mu\left(\bigcup_{j\ge k} A_j\right) \ge \sup_{j \ge k} \mu(A_j)$.

I know that since the set $\bigcap_{j\ge k} A_j$ is decreasing have that $$\mu\left(\bigcap_{j\ge k} A_j\right) \le \mu(A_j)$$ but how where does the infimum come here?

Similarly for $\bigcup_{j\ge k} A_j$ the set is increasing so $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j\ge k} A_j\right) \ge \mu(A_j)$$ but here also where do we get the supremum?

Comment: You're forgetting the *definition* of supremum and infimum.

Answer (score 1):

Which sets are increasing or decreasing ? It's not clear which sets you mean. Indeed the $B_k:= \bigcap_{j\geq k}A_j$'s are decreasing but it's not needed for your question.  As you said $$\mu\left(\bigcap_{j\geq k}A_j\right)\leq \mu(A_j)$$
for all $j\geq k$. Therefore
$$\mu\left(\bigcap_{j\geq k}A_j\right)\leq \inf_{j\geq k}\mu(A_j).$$
Same for the one with the supremum.